# database synchronization tool for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL databases, one is for development and the other is for deployment.

Now, I want to synchronize those databases, any tool should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this tool

Commercial:

http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/dbcomparer

Freeware:
http://www.top4download.com/-1-postgresql-tool-navicat-postgresql-lite-freeware-/spoyoiqt.html

Comment: Navicat Posgresql Lite is so cute, but it does'n support synchronization, so I use Navicat for PostgreSQL (commercial version). Anyway, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep databases in sync, you can use pg_dump and psql to get a dump of the production database and load it to the development database.